# Sequences of arithmetic and geometric mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I am assuming my teacher wants us to conclude they converge by being bounded and monotone, since part (i) is to show that $a_n$ is monotone increasing and $b_n$ is monotone decreasing.

I am confused though because I have never worked with a sequence defined with... another sequence.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: Something's suspicious here: for $\;n=1\;$ in (i) we get $$a_1:=\frac{a+b}2<\sqrt{ab}=:b_1\iff (a-b)^2<0$$which of course is false. Am I missing something? This is the AM-GM inequality upside down!

Comment: Point (i) is backwards. You have $b_1 \leqslant b_n \leqslant b_{n+1} \leqslant a_{n+1}\leqslant a_n \leqslant a_1$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I will point that out to my teacher so he can fix the assignment. And no I have no tried using induction @MarcinŁoś

Comment: Wel, what do you know? I didn't miss something this time! It's going to snow in the Sahara...

Comment: @DonAntonio lol. I'm going to go with marcin's instruction and try induction in a bit. (hey that rhymed)

Comment: ...and I missed one "L" in the first word of my last comment...*sigh*...

Comment: can I really just use induction on the whole thing at once? would my assumed hypothesis just be the entire inequality is true for all n, or do i leave out the n+1 pieces and show them.

Comment: @terribleatmath If $b_n\leq a_n$, then $b_n\leq\sqrt{a_n b_n}\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(a_n+b_n\right)\leq a_n$

Comment: @MarcinŁoś I still don't see how that can lead to an inductive argument, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality,
$$
b_1=\sqrt{ab}\leq\frac{a+b}{2}=a_1
$$

Assume now $b_n\leq a_n$. It follows that
$$
b_n =\sqrt{b_n^2}\leq \sqrt{a_n b_n} = b_{n+1}
$$
$$
a_n=\frac{a_n + a_n}{2}\geq \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}=a_{n+1}
$$
so $a_n$ is decreasing, $b_n$ is increasing. And (again by AM-GM)
$$
b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n b_n}\leq \frac{a_n + b_n}{2}=a_{n+1}
$$
so indeed $b_n\leq b_{n+1}\leq a_{n+1} \leq a_n$, as required.

Comment: thank you. I am confused a bit though by the way my problem is written, since it says that 0<a<b, does that effect the ordering of the AM-GM we have?

Comment: No, $a<b$ is completely irrelevant. I suppose the initial intention could be to define $a_0=a$, $b_0=b$, then it makes the inequality for $a_0$, $b_0$ consistent with the statement of (I). And the problem is, as the reversed inequality shows, not quite carefully stated.

Comment: thank you! this pretty much gives us that these an and bn converge as well, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, as they're monotonic and bounded.

Comment: what do they converge to?

Comment: To the same thing - their [arithmetic-geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean)

Comment: interesting, thanks a lot.

Comment: how could I prove that they have the same limit? I was thinking saying something like $b_n$ is bounded above by $a_n$ and $a_n$ is bounded below by $b_n$ and each are defined recursively using one another

Comment: We know they are convergent. Let $A, B$ be their limits. Can you show the recursive definition implies $A = \frac{1}{2}\left(A+B\right)$?

Comment: I will try to yes, but how does A = 1/2 (A+B)?

Comment: We have $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n)$, take limit of both sides. This requires some justification, of course, but that's basically just continuity of addition.